# Target animation-play-state on sibling hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to animate an SVG path around an element when I hover over that element.

I coded the animation with CSS like this:

```
 #circle-1 {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: 163px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 163px;
    animation-name: circle;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes circle {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

That works fine. It stops working when I try to trigger the animation on hover of a sibling element like so:
HTML

```
<h1 id="link-1">#1</h1>
<svg width="57px" height="46px" viewBox="0 0 57 46" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="circle-1">
        <path d="M1252.39102,182.674299 C1222.56333,182.674299 1186.23852,210.300373 1230.21581,223.998154 C1278.92632,239.170208 1268.93364,185.408886 1243.06946,182.674299" id="Path-3"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
#circle-1 {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: 163px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 163px;
    animation-name: circle;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

#circle-1.active {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes circle {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    var circle1 = document.getElementById("circle-1");
    var link1 = document.getElementById("link-1");
    for (var i = 0; i < circle1.length; i++) {
         link1[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
             circle1.classList.add('active');
             return false;
         });
    }
};
```

Check out the code here:
https://codepen.io/louden/pen/YLeBXB

I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: click not hover, right?

Comment: also why a for loop for a getElementById ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif `mouseover` instead of `click`, I'll fix it. I'm not very good at JS that's why haha

Comment: you have an issue with you SVG, the value used in the path are big and out of the viewbox ... what is the shape?

Comment: I added the original code, it should work now

Comment: @TemaniAfif so the problem is just with the SVG? what should I add in place of the for loop

Comment: `querySelectorAll` (non-live), `getElementsByTagName`(live) etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

```
var circle1 = document.getElementById("circle-1");
```

returns a path element. So what does `for (var i = 0; i < circle1.length; i++) {`
supposed to do there? use `getElementsByTagName` etc for a list...

You path d attribute extends over the svg, so to extend the svg, first clear all that obsolete `widht/height` attribute.  Use the `viewBox` attribute and the `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. That way you get to control the aspect ratio. USe css for width and height.

A working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/40p2fqgc/1/

with infinite animation: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/40p2fqgc/2/

```
<h1 id="link-1">#1</h1>
<svg viewBox="0 0 2000 2000" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path id="circle-1" d="M1252,182 C1222,182 1186,210 1230,223 C1278,239 1268,185 1243,182"/>
</svg>
```

And this is for the click handler you had:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/40p2fqgc/10/

As a side note, `getElementsByTagName` is live so you don't have to call it again.

And here is a canceling animation on mouseout:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/40p2fqgc/15/

Comment: Okay I think you're pretty close. I got rid of the for loop and added some of your JS. The problem is the animation not ending on mouseout. check it out: https://codepen.io/louden/pen/zjRbgv

Comment: Yes that is because you did not specify you want it to disappear on mouseout. Here is that one: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/40p2fqgc/15/

Comment: i removed the class on mouseout. But it still doesn't work. Neither does the fiddle you sent.

Comment: It is not true. Just tested on chrome and firefox. If you click #1, it will start drawing. If you mouseout from #1 it will disappear. What do you want the animation to pause or go back to beginning??